# Find the next element that is not immediate?

Tags: jquery, traversal

I want to find the first span element after class counter, in code something like this:

```
<div class="counter"></div>
<p></p>
<span></span>
```

It seems like the next() function only finds the immediate next element, so something like this:

```
$(".counter").next("span")
```

Won't work. The way I have been using is a bit lengthy and I was wondering if there was a shorter way, it is this:

```
$(".counter").nextAll("span").eq(0)
```

I think the `closest()` method in jQuery 3 will do the trick, but I am using 1.2.6 -- is there a better way to do this (am I just using `next()` wrong?)

Comment: this is how I've done it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30089307/274502

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your method is the best way. And if you feel it doesn't look good just turn it into a plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.firstAfter = function(filter){
 return this.nextAll(filter).eq(0);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Similar to the marked answer but looks a little cleaner using the :first selector:

```
$('.counter').nextAll('span:first')
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the `siblings()` function is what you are looking for.  Try something like this:

```
$(".counter").siblings("span");
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  This is the simplest solution to the problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but doesn't this only find you elements that are immediate siblings to the .counter one.  I think he wants the next on in the page as though we were looking at the source code.

Comment: Hmm, possibly.  siblings() works for the example code he posted.

Comment: Won't siblings take the first of the siblings that matches... which may be before the current element? I think the solution needed here is to exclude all siblings before the current element and only match the first sibling after the current.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the closest method will do the trick, but if so... maybe you can extract the closest method from 1.3 and turning it into a plugin?

I haven't had a chance to try this, but give it a shot.  It can't hurt:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.closest = function (selector) {
    return this.map(function(){
      var cur = this;
      while ( cur && cur.ownerDocument ) {
        if ( $(cur).is(selector) )
          return cur;
        cur = cur.parentNode;
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: CLosest will also search upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(".counter ~ span:first");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This will not work when you have somthing like: <div class='x'></div><p><span></span></p>. The span will not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

$(".counter + span")