# Selecting the first element with a certain class after the selected <input>

Tags: jquery, html

I want to select the first element with a certain class after the selected `<input>`. Here's an example:

#### HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="id_username" />
    <div class="status"></div>

    <input id="id_email" />
    <div class="status"></div>

    <input id="id_password" />
    <div class="status"></div>
</form>
```

#### jQuery:

```
function check_username() {
    $("#id_username").change(function() {
        var user = $("#id_username").val();
        if(user.length >= 3) {
            /* HOW SHOULD I CHANGE THIS ??? */
            $(".status").append('<img src="/site_media/images/loader.gif"> Checking availability...');
        }
    });
}
```

So I want this image "loader.gif" to appear only after the `id_username` input. I will use something similar on `id_email` and `id_password`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the next element that is not immediate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441687/find-the-next-element-that-is-not-immediate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to use:

```
$(this).nextAll('.status').first().append(/* ...stuff... */);
```

This works even if there are separating elements between the the `$(this)` and the `.status`, if the two are immediately adjacent, you can just use:

```
$(this).next('.status').append(/* ...stuff... */);
```

References:

- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

Comment: Why not just `$(this).next('.status')`?

Comment: Because I mis-read the question, and assumed a complexity that wasn't there.

Comment: In the given case, here, yes. On the other hand the OP has specified the importance of the class to the question. So, the selector seemed relatively important in this case.

Comment: Just want to say thank you for pointing .nextAll(). It is really great and that's what I'm going to use.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
function check_username() {
    $("#id_username").change(function() {
        var user = $("#id_username").val();
        if(user.length >= 3) {
           $(this).next(".status").append('<img src="/site_media/images/loader.gif" > Checking availability...');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside event handlers, you use `this` to represent the element.  As for `.status`, you can use `$(this).next('.status')`.

```
function check_username() {
    $("#id_username").change(function() {
        var user = $(this).val();
        if(user.length >= 3) {
           $(this).next('.status').append('<img src="/site_media/images/loader.gif" > Checking availability...');
        }
    });
}
```