# Traverse down to the next element down not immediate and of different type

Tags: javascript, jquery

So in an html structure like this:

```
    <a class="member-main">
      <!-- other divs and html elements -->
    </a>

    <div class="hidden-group-item">
      <!-- other divs and html elements -->
    </div>
```

I want to bind a click event to an html element with class `.member-main` so to show a hidden element `.hidden-group-item`.

There are plenty of those elements repeated in the page in pairs so I'd also like to show only that `.hidden-group-item` immediately below its respective `.member-main`

I'm aiming to do so with a function like below, helped by [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441687/find-the-next-element-that-is-not-immediate):

```
$('body').on('click', '.member-main', function() {
    $(this).next('.hidden-group-item')[0].toggleClass('hide')
});
```

I can get the element associated on click through `this` keyword (if I console log it), but I can't seem to grab that node that'd let me traverse down to the hidden-group-item.

How does `this` work in this case and what would be the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Just remove `[0]` and it will work. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/aod5fktt/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...[0]` returns a nodeElement not a jQuery object that has the function `toggleClass`. Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.member-main', function() {
    $(this).next('.hidden-group-item') // next is already returning one item so no need to try to access the first 
           .toggleClass('hide')
});
```

Comment: I dont think you need `.first()`. To fetch all similar elements you will have to use `nextAll`

Comment: @Rajesh He said there is plenty and he wants only the first (justified by the use of `[0]`).

Comment: @Rajesh Ah never mind just saw that he used `next` not `nextAll`! I'll edit!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks a lot for you answer. I must be about to fall a sleep I thought I tried that plenty of times without success. It's working fine no thanks! I'll accept your answer in a sec

Answer (score 3):

This works as expected

The docs about the `.next()` method says the following:

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

Because you have the onClick handler and you're selecting the currently clicked element as `$(this)` then the *matched set of elements* is only the one you clicked, thus the `next()` call gets the `.hidden-group-item` just beneath it.

**Sample**

```js
$('body').on('click', '.member-main', function() {
  $(this).next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="member-main">
  <!-- other divs and html elements -->
  hello
</a>

<div class="hidden-group-item hide">
  <!-- other divs and html elements -->
  hidden
</div>

<a class="member-main">
  <!-- other divs and html elements -->
  hello
</a>

<div class="hidden-group-item hide">
  <!-- other divs and html elements -->
  hidden
</div>

<a class="member-main">
  <!-- other divs and html elements -->
  hello
</a>

<div class="hidden-group-item hide">
  <!-- other divs and html elements -->
  hidden
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/018ukLn1/)

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can create a snippet (*with HTML, css, and JS only*) using it.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks! I just thought people pasted in that snippet code whenever they used it :D